# Overflow exists but scroll doesn't accommodate it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a website for someone, but the template that I chose was faulty and included a really awkward jscrollpane when on mobile devices. I removed the jscrollpane, but the main content still exists in a jmpress slider. When media queries are active for mobile devices, the content overflows but the scrollbar for body does not adjust for it:
[image]

I am not sure what is causing this. The height for the jmpress slider wrapper is fixed to 475px, but when it's changed, the positioning changes dramatically even when set to absolute. How can I introduce the ability to scroll to the bottom of the content?

A more or less functional version can be found [here](http://liamelliott.github.io). The partial code is below:

```css
@import url('normalize.css');
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400,700");
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700,400italic,700italic&subset=latin,latin-ext,cyrillic");

/* =============================================================================
1. General 
============================================================================= */

body {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #FFF;
  background-image: url(../images/body_backrounds/body_bg_1.png);
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #666665;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  overflow: auto;
  border-top-width: 3px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #E67068;
}
.container > header {
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  padding: 20px 0px 10px 0px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
}
/* ============================================================================= 
2. Content Changer 
============================================================================= */

.jms-slideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 470px;
}
.jms-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.step {
  width: 960px;
  height: 470px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
.step:not(.active) {
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  /* internet explorer */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0)";
  /*IE8*/
}
#jms-content,
#jms-content2,
#jms-content3,
#jms-content4,
#jms-content5 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 470px;
  overflow: ;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
/** NOT SUPPORTED STYLES **/

.not-supported .jms-slideshow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.not-supported .step {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
.not-supported .jms-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
/* ============================================================================= 
3. Main Menu 
============================================================================= */

nav select {
  display: none;
  /* this is just for the mobile display */
}
#menu {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
nav ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease-in;
  transition: all .25s ease-in;
}
nav li {
  border-top: 2px solid #eee;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 0;
}
nav li:hover {
  border-top: 2px solid #cfd0ca;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #cfd0ca;
}
nav li.active {
  border-top: 2px solid #E67068;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E67068;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1em 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: "Oswald", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-shadow: none;
}
nav a:hover a {
  color: #E67068;
}
#nav .active a {
  color: #292929;
  outline: 0;
}
nav a,
nav li {
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .25s ease-in-out;
}
/* ============================================================================= 
4. Mobile Dropdown Menu
 ============================================================================= */

#dd_menu {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Oswald', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  outline: none;
}
/* ============================================================================= 
5. Blocks 
============================================================================= */

.block {
  border-top-width: 2px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #E67068;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  bottom: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}
/* Block for Portfolio Tab */

.block2 {
  border-top-width: 2px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #E67068;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  bottom: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}
/* ============================================================================= 
6.Home Panel 
============================================================================= */

.My_name {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.My_name h1 {
  font-family: "Oswald", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 65px;
  color: #292929;
}
.My_name h3 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: 200;
  color: #555556;
}
.portrait {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.portrait img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
.general_info {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.general_info p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/* social icons */

.social_icons ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.social li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.social li a {
  outline: 0;
}
.social img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.social img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
/* personal info */

ul.personal-info {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul.personal-info li {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
ul.personal-info .title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Oswald', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #E67068;
  border-radius: 22px 22px 22px 22px;
  color: #333;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 13px;
}
ul.personal-info .value {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
ul.personal-info .available {
  /* Font Color For Freelance Status = Available */
  color: #6f803b;
}
ul.personal-info .not_available {
  /* Font Color For Freelance Status = Not Available */
  color: #803b3b;
}
/* ============================================================================= 
7. Resume Panel 
============================================================================= */

.detailsCol {
  width: 100%;
}
.detailsCol h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.detailsCol ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.detailsCol ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-color: #E67068;
}
.detailsCol ul li p {
  margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
.detailsCol span {
  font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: #b4b4b4;
}
.detailsCol span.date {
  color: #E67068;
  float: right;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 11px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* Skills */

.skillsInfo {
  margin: 10px 0 0px 0;
}
.skillsInfo em {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #292929;
  font-family: "Oswald", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
.skill-container {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12px;
  border-color: #E67068;
  border-width: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.skill {
  background-color: #ffa099;
  height: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  padding: 0 -1px 0 1px;
}
.skill-10 {
  width: 10%;
}
.skill-20 {
  width: 20%;
}
.skill-30 {
  width: 30%;
}
.skill-40 {
  width: 40%;
}
.skill-50 {
  width: 50%;
}
.skill-60 {
  width: 60%;
}
.skill-70 {
  width: 70%;
}
.skill-80 {
  width: 80%;
}
.skill-90 {
  width: 90%;
}
.skill-100 {
  width: 100%;
}
/* =============================================================================
8.Services Panel 
============================================================================= */

.services {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.service {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.service h4 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.service img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}
.service img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(720deg);
  transform: rotate(720deg);
}
/* ============================================================================= 
9. Portfolio Panel 
============================================================================= */

.portfolio {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
/* Portfolio Items */

.portfolio li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.portfolio a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.portfolio h3 {
  color: #E67068;
}
.portfolio img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/* Portfolio Filter */

ul.filter {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  list-style: none;
}
ul.filter li a {
  float: right;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 5px 7px 5px 7px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  line-height: 13px;
  background: #cfd0ca;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 80ms ease-in;
  /* property duration timing-function delay */
  -moz-transition: all 80ms ease-in;
  /* property duration timing-function delay */
  transition: all 80ms ease-in;
  /* property duration timing-function delay */
}
.filter a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #E67068;
}
.filter .current a {
  color: #FFF;
  background: #E67068;
}
/* 3D Boxes Rotate Styles */

.rollover {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.short {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.front {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}
.back {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -80% !important;
}
.rollover:hover .back,
.rollover:focus .back {
  z-index: 2;
}
.rollover:hover .front,
.rollover:focus .front {
  z-index: 1;
}
.fade .rollover .front {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}
.fade .rollover .back {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}
.fade .rollover:hover .front,
.fade .rollover:focus .front {
  opacity: 0;
}
.fade .rollover:hover .back,
.fade .rollover:focus .back {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flip .rollover {
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -ms-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}
.flip .cube {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
  -o-transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
  transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0) rotateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -ms-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}
.flip .front {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
}
.flip .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.flip .rollover:hover .cube,
.flip .rollover:focus .cube {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.box .front {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 60px) scale(0.9, 0.9);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 60px) scale(0.85, 0.85);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 60px) scale(0.85, 0.85);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 60px) scale(0.85, 0.85);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 60px) scale(0.85, 0.85);
}
.box .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translate3d(0, 0, 60px) scale(0.9, 0.9);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg) translate3d(0, 0, 60px) scale(0.85, 0.85);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg) translate3d(0, 0, 60px) scale(0.85, 0.85);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg) translate3d(0, 0, 60px) scale(0.85, 0.85);
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translate3d(0, 0, 60px) scale(0.85, 0.85);
}
/* ============================================================================= 
10. Contact Panel 
============================================================================= */

#contactform {
  margin-top: -7px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
.info_fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  bottom: 5px;
  background: none;
  border: 0px;
}
label {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 2px;
}
input[type="text"] textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
}
/* ============================================================================= 
11. Media Queries 
============================================================================= */

/* Smaller than standard 960 (devices and browsers) */

@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
  .step {
    width: 960px;
    height: 470px;
  }
}
/* Tablet Portrait size to standard 960 (devices and browsers) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
  .step {
    width: 768px;
    height: 470px;
  }
}
/* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .step {
    width: 300px;
    height: 470px;
  }
  .block {
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #E67068;
    padding: 40px 40px 40px -20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  }
  .end {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  .block2 {
    border-top-width: 2px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-color: #E67068;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  #dd_menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .My_name h1 {
    font-family: "Oswald", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 45px;
    color: #292929;
  }
  .My_name h3 {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #555556;
  }
  .portfolio img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .portfolio {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
  }
  .jspDrag {
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #999999;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.2;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  a.trigger {
    display: none;
  }
}
/* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .step {
    width: 420px;
    height: 470px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>First Last - Toronto Software Developer</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="description" content="The best in quality web and software development in the Toronto, Ontario area. Clients receive simple, robust solutions that are valuable to all." />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.qtip.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- jmpress plugin -->
  <script src="js/jms.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- extends the jmpress plugin -->
  <script src="js/jmpress.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- jQuery Easing 1.3 -->
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Detect Mobile Browser -->
  <script src="js/detectmobilebrowser.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- mousewheel -->
  <script src="js/mousewheel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Quicksand -->
  <script src="js/jquery.quicksand.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- prettyPhoto -->
  <script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- qTip -->
  <script src="js/jquery.qtip.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- jQuery mobile gmaps -->
  <script src="js/jquery.mobilegmap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Contact Form -->
  <script src="js/contact_form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Settings -->
  <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Modernizr -->
  <script src="js/modernizr.custom.48780.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE7.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE8.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

  <noscript>
    <style>
      .step {
        position: relative;
      }
      .step:not(.active) {
        opacity: 1;
        filter: alpha(opacity=99);
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=99)";
      }
      .step:not(.active) a.jms-link {
        opacity: 1;
        margin-top: 40px;
      }
    </style>
  </noscript>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <div class="sixteen columns">
        <div class="My_name">
          <!-- <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"> -->
          <h1>First Last</h1>
          <h3>Software Developer</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Primary Navigation -->
      <nav id="menu" class="sixteen columns">
        <ul id="nav">
          <!-- <nav> -->
          <li class="active">
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#resume">Resume</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#services">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Dropdown Menu For Mobile Device -->
        <select id="dd_menu">
          <option value="#home">Home</option>
          <option value="#resume">Resume</option>
          <option value="#services">Services</option>
          <option value="#contact">Contact</option>
        </select>
        <!-- Dropdown Menu End -->
      </nav>
      <!-- Primary Navigation End -->
    </header>
    <!-- End Part of Title and Menu Navigation -->

    <section id="jms-slideshow" class="jms-slideshow sixteen columns">

      <!-- Home Subpage -->
      <div id="home" class="step" data-x="6000" data-y="1600" data-rotate="0" data-scale="15">
        <div id="jms-content">
          <p>...</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Resume Subpage -->
      <div id="resume" class="step" data-x="18000" data-y="2800" data-rotate="-30" data-scale="5">
        <div id="jms-content2">
          <p>...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Resume Subpage -->

      <!-- Services Subpage -->
      <div id="services" class="step" data-x="22000" data-y="2800" data-rotate="30" data-scale="3">
        <div id="jms-content3">
          <p>...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Services Subpage -->

      <!-- Contact Subpage -->
      <div id="contact" class="step" data-x="30000" data-y="6500" data-rotate="30" data-scale="3">
        <div id="jms-content5">

          <p>...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End Contact Subpage -->

    </section>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't have to do with javascript. I troubleshoted for you. It's just a CSS issue caused by you.

I visited your website and changed this and worked for me (using chrome).

The reason why you have this issue is `overflow: hidden;`

```
<div class="jms-wrapper step-home delegating-step-home" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;" tabindex="0">
```

Just in CSS:

```
.jms-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    overflow: inherit !important;
}

body {
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Your welcome!

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find that code in any of the source. What is step-home and delegating-step home? I can only find jms-wrapper in the stylesheet.

Comment: I see. I made the change in style.css, yet there was no difference in the behaviour of the site. Do you know why this is?

Comment: Nope you do not add it to your stylesheet. I mean on http://liamelliott.github.io/.

Comment: Oh. I tried it on my local copy, but the change didn't work. I'll make sure I have it updated on the github site.

Comment: please change to `overflow: inherit !important;` to this! The ( !important ) is important :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112092/discussion-between-canadait-and-doctype-html).

Answer (score 0):

I do think this is something to do with your JS, the jmpress.js script in particular. You will notice that you can actually scroll down the page providing your mouse isn't over the `.jms-wrapper` element. I managed to scroll down whilst having my cursor to the left of the picture. Once you hover over the image, you can't scroll anymore.

I don't think this is a simple overflow case. If you disable JS completely on the page, it will work fine. Adding `pointer-events:none;` to `.jms-wrapper` also fixes it (though i wouldn't recommend using it, it was just for my own debugging purposes). However, this leads me to believe that something in your js file is disabling the scroll. A quick look in your jmpress.js file reveals this.

```
    function scrollFix() {
        (function fix() {
            if ($(container)[0].tagName === "BODY") {
                try {
                    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
                } catch(e) {}
            }
            $(container).scrollTop(0);
            $(container).scrollLeft(0);
            function check() {
                if ($(container).scrollTop() !== 0 ||
                    $(container).scrollLeft() !== 0) {
                        fix();
                    }
            }
            setTimeout(check, 1);
            setTimeout(check, 10);
            setTimeout(check, 100);
            setTimeout(check, 200);
            setTimeout(check, 400);
        }());
    }
```

This could potentially be the culprit! If not, its worth taking a look through the jmpress.js file for any instances where the default scroll functionality might be altered